# Error en import de android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

[image]
Me aparece error en "android", pienso que se tiene que agregar una referencia, pero desconozco donde, agradecería su ayuda, gracias.

Comment: Bienvenida, recuerda agregar el codigo como texto por favor a tus preguntas, revisa [ask]. Es ejercicio de un libro? que version de Android Studio estas usando?, saludos

Comment: Android Studio 4.0
Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020
Runtime version: 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01 amd64. No, no es ejercicio de un libro, saludos

Comment: Seguramente ya hayas resuelto el problema, no obstante... has agregado los respectivos "apply plugin" al proyecto ? apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'